# Shell tab opened via script hangs after Ctrl+C on running process

Tags: shell-script, zsh, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
START_FOREMAN='/usr/bin/zsh -c "source /home/user/.zshrc; foreman start" zsh'
xfce4-terminal --tab -H -T app-server --working-directory=/home/user/git/app -e $START_FOREMAN

xfce4-terminal --tab -H -T api-server --working-directory=/home/user/git/api -e $START_FOREMAN
```

Both of these commands depend on env settings ([`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) configuration) so I source my `./zshrc` file before running the [`foreman`](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) gem.

However, if I run this and then attempt to `Ctrl+C` out of the long running process - the shell ends and I never get my prompt back.

Note: running foreman start in a new shell in the same directory returns the prompt to me after `Ctrl+C`.

Edit: People seem to be getting hung up on foreman being the issue which I believe is not the case as this hangs with running say `./gradlew bootRun` or any long running process.

Foreman definitely exits:

```
^CSIGINT received
16:13:09 system       | sending SIGTERM to all processes
16:13:10 api.1 | exited with code 130
```

As does Spring boot:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:291)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:bootRun FAILED
> Building 100%
```

At this point there's nothing I can do - everything is ignored and I have to close the tab.

Comment: When you say "if I run this" what exactly does that mean?

Comment: The script above.

Answer (score 0):

What you observe is a combination of two things:

1. Ctrl-C sends INT to the process group, which means that not only your long-running process but also a *zsh* process it is running in, will be terminated simultaneously (and it will not have a chance to restart itself).
2. xfce4-terminal, will not close the tab, after your process is over, due to the -H flag:

> −H, −−hold
>   Causes the terminal to be kept around after the child command has terminated

which makes it look like it is hanging

A simplest possible test case for this might look something like this:

```
CMD=xeyes
START=$'/usr/bin/zsh -c \''$CMD$'; /usr/bin/zsh\''
xfce4-terminal --tab -H -T mycommand --working-directory=$HOME -e "$START"
```

If you launch this, the "xeyes" will be following you, until you press *Ctrl+C*, at which point they will close and your terminal will appear to be hanging.

But if instead of clicking *Ctrl+C* you will just kill the xeyes themselves (i.e. with an xkill, or a window manager task bar), a *zsh* session will start as intended.

A workaround for this, is to intercept the SIGINT and re-launch the shell,like this:

```
CMD=xeyes
START=$'/usr/bin/zsh -c \'trap "exec /usr/bin/zsh" INT;'$CMD$'; exec /usr/bin/zsh\''
xfce4-terminal --tab -H -T mycommand --working-directory=$HOME -e "$START"
```

Note, that you might also want to remove '-H', to make the tab close, when you exit the shell.